# call Java Method using JavaScript inside JSP Page

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I created a Java Web Project. In this project I have one JSP file 'test_page.jsp'.
JSP page content is given below

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <script src="jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function testjs() {
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/LDAPAuth/DoAuth', cache:false, success:function(data){
                        alert(data);    
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("failed to fecth data");
                    }
                });
            }
            
            function checkBoxValidation() {
                document.GetUserSessionform.action ="https://potest.com/jsp/custom/getUserDetails.jsp";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" leftmargin="10" topmargin="0">
        <form name='GetUserSessionform' id="GetUserSessionform" method='post' action="/" onSubmit="return checkBoxValidation()">
            <table height="100%" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table align="center" width="450px" height="100px">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="1" style="float:left">AdminId <span style="color:red">*</Span></td>
                                <td colspan="1" style="float:left"><input type="text" name="User_ID" id="User_ID"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="1" style="float:left">Password <span style="color:red">*</Span></td>
                                <td colspan="1" style=" float:left"><input type="password" name="Password" id="Password"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="1s" align="center" style="float:left"><input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="testjs()"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td colspan="1s" align="center" style="float:left"><label id="lblMessage">
                            </label></td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to call below Java Class Method 'doGet' which is inside this project and get the 'mesg' value as response.

```
package com.tst.nam;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class DoAuth {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String mesg = "success";
        try {
            System.out.println("Inside doGet>>>>>");
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(mesg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in doGet>>>>>" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

My web.xml content is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>LDAPAuth</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DoAuth</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.tst.nam.DoAuth</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DoAuth</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/DoAuth</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I click on Submit button I am getting an alert 'failed to fecth data' and also not able to see any sysout in log file. In browser console I am getting below error and when
[image]
Please help me on this.

Comment: What is the issue? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam When I clicked submit button I am getting alert 'failed to fecth data' and also not able to see any sysout in log file.

Comment: Open the console of the browser and check what is the error.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I have updated the error screen shot in my question.